# Send email alert to Account lookup fields, based on Opportunity Criteria

Tags: apex, workflow, relationships, process-builder, email-alert

I'm hoping someone can help me with this dead-end I've gotten myself into.

Here's the use case:

There are two lookup fields on the Account object that pull a User in our org: "Business Consultant" and "Sales Lead".

When an "Upgrade" opportunity is created, I need a way to send an email notification to the Business Consultant and Sales Lead of the corresponding Account.

Here's an example:

If User A is the Business Consultant of Company A, and User B is the Sales Lead of Company A, an email needs to be sent to both User A and User B whenever an opportunity with the type "Upgrade" is created for Company A.

I'm hoping I won't need to write a trigger or create a bunch of additional fields and/or relationships to pull this off, but I'm looking forward to the suggestions from this site.

Comment: Honestly the fastest result will probably be to learn basic trigger syntax and write one, this is a really straightforward trigger and this community will be able to address issues you may encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the new Flow builder in salesforce?  You can easily create automated flows to trigger and send an email to any related reference without code.   We use this today and is very intuitive, with no code.

**Setup> Flow** will load with a how-to video

next, you'll need to go to **Setup> Process Builder** to act as a trigger and run the flow you build.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_overview.htm

Here's a screen shotof a flow I use to send an email alert to a designated contact for our locations:

[image]

Comment: I used the process builder to help me do this. Success! Thanks

Comment: Great to hear and good job on running this!